# How to remove or hide the application button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I'm new to android studio and I'm trying to remove a button from my videos app

I have 4 buttons in my app Android : Recent,Featured,Popular,Random and Live.

I would like to delete the Live button, but I am not able to

If necessary I can take a screenshot of my android studio.

I don't necessarily need to remove the button if I have another way to just hide it, that would be a big help too

I followed my code:

If necessary I can take a screenshot of my android studio.

```
package com.app.materialvideo.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.duolingo.open.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager;
import com.app.materialvideo.Config;
import com.app.materialvideo.R;
import com.app.materialvideo.utils.CustomTabLayout;
import com.app.materialvideo.utils.SharedPref;

import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.FILTER_LIVE;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.FILTER_video;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.ORDER_FEATURED;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.ORDER_LIVE;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.ORDER_POPULAR;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.ORDER_RANDOM;
import static com.app.materialvideo.utils.Constant.ORDER_RECENT;

public class FragmentTabLayout extends Fragment {

    public RelativeLayout tab_background;
    public CustomTabLayout smartTabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    public RtlViewPager viewPagerRTL;
    public int tab_count = 5;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    View view;

    public FragmentTabLayout() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout_rtl, container, false);
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_layout, container, false);
        }
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(getActivity());
        tab_background = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_background);
        smartTabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorToolbarDark));
            smartTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentDark));
        } else {
            tab_background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        initViewPager();
        return view;

    }

    public void initViewPager() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            viewPagerRTL = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_rtl);
            viewPagerRTL.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
            viewPagerRTL.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
            smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPagerRTL));

        } else {
            viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tab_count));
            smartTabLayout.post(() -> smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager));
        }
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        int noOfItems;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int noOfItems) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
            this.noOfItems = noOfItems;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_RECENT, FILTER_video);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_FEATURED, FILTER_video);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_POPULAR, FILTER_video);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_RANDOM, FILTER_video);
            }  {
                return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_LIVE, FILTER_LIVE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return noOfItems;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPageTitle(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_recent);
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_featured);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_popular);
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_random);
            }  {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_live);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you don't want to remove a classic button, but a Tab button used inside a TabLayout.

**If you want to remove it** , easiest way would be to remove the last condition in your if else statements that deal with displaying and handling this button.

From the code you posted should be

**Here**

```
{
            return getResources().getString(R.string.menu_live);
}
```

and here, as i think these two deal with the "Live" button.

```
{
            return Fragmentvideo.newInstance(ORDER_LIVE, FILTER_LIVE);
}
```

As well as reduce the value passed to the ViewPager Adapter "noOfItems" variable by 1. In your situation, I think the variable is "tabCount" and that should be set to 4 ( down from 5). I see it's used in many places and changing this should deal with all cases.

**If hiding is also good, then this code should also work.**

Just use it inside onCreateView(). The code is in Kotlin and works on a default TabLayout, but i am not sure if it will work as i see you use a custom one.

```
tabLayout?.getTabAt(4)?.view?.visibility = View.GONE
```

You need to pass the index of the tab you want to hide, so in your case, you have 5 tabs, so the index is 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you know id of the button.

```
 view.findViewById(R.id.btn_firs).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```